# How to Document Custom Properties and Methods in Express Request and Response Objects in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jsdoc

I'm working on an Express.js project in JavaScript and would like to document custom properties and methods in the `Express Response` objects using JSDoc comments.

Specifically, I want to add a custom `error` and `success` function to the Response object to handle error responses in a consistent way.

i have tried with `@typedef` but it is still showing this warning, not throwing error - `Property 'error' may not exist on type 'Response<any, Record<string, any>, number>'`

```
@typedef {object} CustomResponse
@property {Function} error - A function to handle error responses.
```

```
/**
 * *Route for handling 404 Not Found errors.
 * *This middleware will catch any request that does not match any other route handlers.
 *
 * @param {import('express').Request} req - The Express request object.
 * @param {import('express').Response} res - The Express response object.
 * @param {import('express').NextFunction} next - The next function to pass control to the next middleware.
 *
 * @date 07 September 2023
 */
app.all('*', (req, res) => {
    return res.error(
        HTTPStatus.NOT_FOUND,
        'The requested resource could not be found but may be available in the future'
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking inspiration from [how to do this with the Request object in TypeScript](https://blog.logrocket.com/extend-express-request-object-typescript/)...

Add a TypeScript type definition file to your project. For example, you could add a file at the path `src/types/express/index.d.ts` with the content:

```js
// to make the file a module and avoid the TypeScript error
export {}

declare global {
  namespace Express {
    export interface Response {
      error: Function;
    }
  }
}
```

Then, make sure that your [jsconfig.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig) file looks at TypeScript files

```js
{
  //...
  "include": [
    "**/*.js",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
  //...
}
```

Once this is setup, VS Code should recognize that your `res` variable has an `error` function. Your `TypeScript` definition file can also reference types in other `.js` files in your code base using syntax such as `import('path/to/file/exporting/class.js').default`.